# Oracle combining columns with comma separated values

Tags: oracle11g

I have one table with values like "1,2,3,4,5,6,7" per row like

```
ID Value
101  5,6,7
201  8,9,3
301  3,4,5
```

Value column values are foreign key of other table B
Table B

```
5 A
6 C
7 N
```

Is there any way i can join these two tables together in one query?
I want to pass 101 and get A C N values.

Comment: Could use some formatting and its hard to follow what exactly you are wanting.

Comment: By definition, you cannot have a foreign key in B that points to the `value` column in A if 5 is a valid value in B rather than the string `5,6,7`.  Do you really have a foreign key?  If you do, the data model must be different.

Answer (score 3):

if your model is as shown, something like this?

```
select a.id, listagg(new_value, ',') within group (order by new_value) new_value
  from a 
       inner join b 
               on ','||a.value||',' like '%,'|| b.value ||',%'
 group by a.id
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/74e46/1